# Is there a word to describe the virtue of "to do something and ask for nothing in return"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering if there is a positive, formal counterpart to the slang "No strings attached" to describe, for example, a parent's unquestioned devotion to their children, or the virtue of someone's "a friend in need is a friend in deed", help first, question later mentality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is *altruism*

**altruism, n.**

*Pronunciation:  Brit.   /ˈaltrʊɪz(ə)m/ , U.S. /ˈæltrəˌwɪzəm/ , /ˈælˌtruˌɪzəm/*

*1. Disinterested or selfless concern for the well-being of others, esp. as a principle of action. Opposed to selfishness, egoism, or (in early use) egotism.*

OED

Answer (score 4):

*Philanthropist* might be an alternative to *altruism* already suggested –

From Oxford English Dictionary (OED) –

> philanthropist, n.
>
> A benefactor of humankind; one who behaves benevolently towards others; a practitioner of philanthropy.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider *altruism*, ‘Disinterested or selfless concern for the well-being of others’ in the OED’s definition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was writing acknowledgement section of my Thesis. I guess altruistic is probably too strong of a word. But selfless works, why didn't I think of that!

Comment: If you want the noun, it's _selflessness_.